# Getting Response Code '404' when run HTTP requestt

Tags: jmeter

. I'm a newbie of JMeter
. I'm trying to get HTTP request to view page 'https://....', but getting error Response Code '404', I don't know why.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ruk.png ]

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/718C6.png ]

[3] https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLn8k.png ]

Comment: You need to read about get & post http methods, sign-in may be a post method in your case which needs request body.

Comment: '404' is the HTTP code for "page not found". The web server doesn't know what to do with your requests; there is something wrong with your URL.

Comment: . The web is 'https://reliantehsdev.azureedge.net/account/sign-in'

When I set the protocol is 'empty'. The result return:
- HTTP Request-0 : this is return Response Code: 200
- HTTP Request-1 : this is return Response Code: 404
But the actual web had content 'https'